# How to plot multiple categorical variables in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

My data set contains several categorical variables that I would like visualise  to see the distribution.

For example, if I wanted to visualise the 4 variables (manufacturer, trans, fl, class) in the mpg data set in ggplot2, I have to write 4 lines of code:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(manufacturer)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip()
ggplot(mpg, aes(trans)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip()
ggplot(mpg, aes(fl)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip()
ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip()
```

Resulting barplot:

[image]

How can I write a code to do this more efficiently? loop? apply function? I would like to see each chart one at a time, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea to use `lapply` is one solution.

This requires `aes_string` to be used instead `aes`.

**Single plots**

This creates single plots per column (name) you supply as first argument to `lapply`:

```
lapply(c("manufacturer", "trans", "fl", "class"),
  function(col) {
    ggplot(mpg, aes_string(col)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip()
  })
```

**Combined plots**

If you require all plots on one plotting area, you can use `miscset::ggplotGrid`:

```
library(miscset) # install from CRAN if required
ggplotGrid(ncol = 2,
  lapply(c("manufacturer", "trans", "fl", "class"),
    function(col) {
        ggplot(mpg, aes_string(col)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip()
    }))
```

The result looks like:

[image]

Comment: That's fantastic! Thanks for the quick response @setempler. Is there a way to order the bars by count?

Comment: @rishi Yes, described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph - answer of Alex Brown

Comment: @setempler Can we label the values for each graph and applying the colour for each bar?
thankyou.